# Aimeos migration error; SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'taniscart.users' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, cart

HI I am trying to Install Aimeos for laravel 5.2, After Installation and database configuration config/shop.php when i am running *php artisan migration* I have found this error. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqA6i.png) Here is my users table code

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AimeosUsersTable extends Migration {

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->string('salutation', 8)->default('');
            $table->string('company', 100)->default('');
            $table->string('vatid', 32)->default('');
            $table->string('title', 64)->default('');
            $table->string('firstname', 64)->default('');
            $table->string('lastname', 64)->default('');
            $table->string('address1')->default('');
            $table->string('address2')->default('');
            $table->string('address3')->default('');
            $table->string('postal', 16)->default('');
            $table->string('city')->default('');
            $table->string('state')->default('');
            $table->string('langid', 5)->nullable();
            $table->char('countryid', 2)->nullable();
            $table->string('telephone', 32)->default('');
            $table->string('telefax', 32)->default('');
            $table->string('website')->default('');
            $table->date('birthday')->nullable();
            $table->smallInteger('status')->default('1');
            $table->date('vdate')->nullable();
            $table->string('editor')->default('');

            $table->index('langid');
            $table->index(array('status', 'lastname', 'firstname'));
            $table->index(array('status', 'address1'));
            $table->index('lastname');
            $table->index('address1');
            $table->index('city');
            $table->index('postal');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->dropIndex('users_langid_index');
            $table->dropIndex('users_status_lastname_firstname_index');
            $table->dropIndex('users_status_address1_index');
            $table->dropIndex('users_lastname_index');
            $table->dropIndex('users_address1_index');
            $table->dropIndex('users_city_index');
            $table->dropIndex('users_postal_index');

            $table->dropColumn(array(
                'salutation', 'company', 'vatid', 'title', 'firstname',
                'lastname', 'address1', 'address2', 'address3', 'postal', 'city',
                'state', 'langid', 'countryid', 'telephone', 'telefax', 'website',
                'birthday', 'status', 'vdate', 'editor'
            ));
        });
    }

}
```

still solve the problem. any suggestion???

Answer (score 0):

Did you add these lines to your composer.json before you've executed "composer update"?

```
"scripts": {
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan vendor:publish --tag=public --force",
        "php artisan vendor:publish",
        "php artisan migrate",
    ]
}
```

Especially the "php artisan vendor:publish" is important

Comment: Yes, I did

 "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize",
            "php artisan vendor:publish --tag=public --force",
            "php artisan vendor:publish",
            "php artisan migrate"
        ]

Comment: Are the default Laravel database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php and database/migrations/2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php migration files are missing in your installation?